# How to find if an object value is included in another object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, lodash

I have an object

```
obj1 = {
    key: 'a,b,c,d'
}
```

another object

```
obj2 = {
    key: 'b,a'
}
```

I want to check if `obj2` values are included in `obj1`.

I tried the below method but it returns `false` for the above two objects

```
function includesValues(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.values(obj1).every(v1 =>
    Object.values(obj2).some(v2 =>
      v2.split(',').forEach((val) => {
        v1.includes(val.toString());
      })
    )
  );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhuman/4tv9cwjd/1705/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: change `forEach` to `every`

Comment: @dandavis perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return the v1.includes statement, because it's not implicitly returned from the block.

```js
obj1 = {
 key: 'a,b,c,d'
};
obj2 = {
 key: 'a,b'
};
        
function includesValues(obj1, obj2) {
 return Object.values(obj1).every(v1 =>
  Object.values(obj2).some(v2 =>
   v2.split(',').every((val) => {
    return v1.split(',').includes(val.toString()); // Return this
   })
  )
 );
}

console.log(includesValues(obj1,obj2));
```